# How to make only the valid active page of a multilevel menu active with - ".nav li.current-menu-item a"?

Tags: php, menus, css

Why, if I write - .nav li.current-menu-item a {}, then all items in the submenu of the active page will be highlighted, how can I make sure that only the really active item is highlighted? If I write  - 'li', then everything works fine - .nav li.current-menu-item {}, but I need it with the - "a" .

My code variant - "a" does not work correctly -

```css
.nav  li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #ff7676;;
}
```

[image: a variant]

My code variant "li" works fine -

```css
.nav  li.current-menu-item {
    background-color: rgb(175, 173, 32);
}
```

[image: variant li]

My menu code

```php
<?php
if(has_nav_menu('head_menu')){
    wp_nav_menu(array (
        'theme_location' => 'head_menu',
        'container'=> false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav',
        'items_wrap' => ' <ul class="%2$s">%3$s' . $mobile_search . '</ul>',
        'depth' => 30,
        'walker' => new Cust_Nav()
    ) );
}
?>
```

```php
class Cust_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'dropdown-menu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";
    }
  
  /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    
        if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $classes)){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown';
        }

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */

        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item,$args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = $item->xfn;
        }
        $atts['href']         = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
         *     @type string $aria-current The aria-current attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $value ) && '' !== $value && false !== $value ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output  = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this:  `.nav  li.current-menu-item > a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely a CSS question, and has nothing to do with WordPress, but the answer is simple enough. You need to use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

```
.nav li.current-menu-item > a {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works now.